# RESTful APIs for WSO2 Identity Server 5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Are there restful APIs for managing users and registering Service provider for SAML2 Single-Sign On. I have a lot of applications that are using the identity server and would like them to self-register as providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All user store operations would be exposed via web services. External application can use these web services to add/delete/update/get AD users and groups. Identity Server expose two type of web services.

1. REST web service according to the SCIM provisioning specification. Details from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider). This would be the standard way to do this.
2. SOAP based Web service. You can find more detail from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2013/12/10/user-role-management-with-wso2-identity-server-apis/)

Also if you want to add service providers without using UI.  You can also do that by using web service in Identity Server.  It has only exposed as SOAP based service which is called as `IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService`

Comment: Are there plans to expose other functionalities like the IdentitySAMLSSOConfigService via REST interfaces?

Comment: Sorry..  It may be in carbon 5.0.0 release which would be around 2015.But you can front some ESB and expose this SOAP service as REST API

Comment: could you @Asela please very briefly explain what tools/steps you use to generate the user api client? WSDL2Java, maven plugin? or maybe it seems you rather rely on the stub jar, rather than generating it yourself? thx

Comment: If you are using java,  it is easy to use the stub. This stub has been shipped with Identity Server. Also, if you like there is wsdl-java tool that can regenerate the stub. You can see the pom.xml file that is used to generate above stub from here http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/service-stubs/org.wso2.carbon.um.ws.api.stub/4.2.0/pom.xml   If not, just to try out you can use soapUI tool http://charithaka.blogspot.fi/2013/06/invoking-wso2-carbon-admin-services.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried SCIM? It provides a REST API out of the box:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+SCIM+Service+Provider